# google map places api not giving proper results in android

Tags: android, android-maps

In my app I'm trying to get location of beauty salons near my current location. For this purpose I'm using google places API. As mentioned in the link I'm trying to get all information about beauty salon near by me. For this I'm using following code

```
private void onPerformSearch() {

    double lat=gePoint_pt.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
    double lon=gePoint_pt.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

    String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?";
    url=url.concat("&location="+lat+","+lon);
    //url=url.concat("&location="+gePoint_pt);
    url=url.concat("&radius="+1000);
    url=url.concat("&types="+"beauty"+"_"+"salon");
    url=url.concat("&name=");
    url=url.concat("&sensor="+"true");
    url=url.concat("&key=*******");
    Log.i("url=========",""+url);
    try {

        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) 
        { 
            //get web service responce
            String res_str=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.i("RESPONCE======",""+res_str);
            if(res_str!=null)
            {
                parse(res_str);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}
```

But now my problem is,whenever I call this method I always get "zero-result" as a response for beauty salons. But when I try the same for atm machines it gives me proper results. When I try to search same things using google map,it gives me proper response .i.e. It displays all the beauty salons near by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me :

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=beauty%20salon&mrt=yp&sll=lat,lon&output=kml

where lat, lon is the double latitude and longitude.

`edit:` This was answered by OP, use the `name` parameter instead of `types`, which is very weird because the Places documentation clearly says use the `types` parameter. Also this is not needed in USA/UK etc, only for places in India. I hope Google fixes this soon.

Comment: @reno...thanks for response...but in the places API docs they mentioned beauty_salon in the supported type section...thts why i used it...can u please give me more detail about this...bcoz i'm not able to open url u have mentioned....

Comment: You are right, I've checked the docs. Can you tell me your lat, lon? The url that I've used gives a kml that is similar to an xml. It is a file that Google Earth can open.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?&location=19.169255,72.959416&radius=1000&types=beauty salon&name=&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCALnYwpK5B90jgiSG2G0O4F5-dZz5gxEI........this is my url..which give me zero results as responce...

Comment: You are right, it seems to be some kind of bug from Google's end. However with my URL it gives 10 locations. I've tested your URL with places in USA and England, it works fine. Some how places in India does not work at all.

Comment: @reno...finally got my ans...i went through forums on Google places API...and i replaced name field with the beauty salon and its working now...thanks anyways for Ur help...